# Turning back around after Lcha Dodi

Tags: song-poetry, kabbalat-shabbat

After [Lcha dodi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekhah_Dodi) at what point exactly do the congregants and the Chazzan supposed to turn Back around?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3376/lecha-dodi-last-stanza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Nushach Ashkenaz the congregants say the stanza **prior** to the Chazan and thus should turn around when they complete saying Boi B'Shalom **before** the Chazzan says it.

By Nusach Sefard the congregants say the stanza **after** the Chazan and thus should turn around when they complete saying Boi B'Shalom, which is after the Chazzan already turned back around.

Comment: Nowadays, the vast majority of shuls [that I've been to] don't sing it responsively anymore.

Comment: @R'IM, I suspect most _nusach S'farad_ places do. Certainly most I've been to do.

Comment: I've davened in many Nusach Sfard shuls, including my current primary one and the one I grew up with, although perhaps my experience with hardcore Chassidish Nusach Sefard or Nusach Ari is limited. I do recall seeing responsive Lecha Dodi at KAJ, which is as Ashkenaz as they come.

Comment: most of the Shuls I have Davened in do it responsively

Comment: The New York area and many very large communities keep the original minhag of doing it responsively. Out of town smaller places have everybody sing along with the chazzan probably due to the fact that many of the people would not say the words by themselves, similar to the singing bircas hamazon together phenomenon.