# Turning to the right vs. practice

Tags: minhag, chanuka, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, chazal, kabbalat-shabbat

[Mishna Berura 676:10](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P117Lc2t41sC&lpg=PA203&dq=mishna%20berura%20%22whenever%20you%20make%20a%20turning%2C%20it%20should%20only%20be%20towards%20the%20right%22&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=mishna%20berura%20%22whenever%20you%20make%20a%20turning,%20it%20should%20only%20be%20towards%20the%20right%22&f=false) quotes our sages: "Whenever you make a turning, it should only be towards the right".

However, it appears to me that we usually turn to the left (counter-clockwise) when shaking the Lulav and saying *Bo'i Kala* during [Lecha Dodi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9295/3073)

Is counter-clockwise called "turning right", or is there another explanation?

Comment: Hakafos are going round something, not spinning round .

Comment: @CashCow Good point. I'll limit it to those that involve actual spinning.

Comment: @GershonGold Was already linked. Maybe you mean to state something?

Comment: @GershonGold I didn't realize that. If you have a source, you may want to answer that question (thus providing an alternative to the Arizal way).

Answer (score 2):

[Orach Chaim 651:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=248) says that one should circle to the right when shaking the Lulav. That is the Minhag Ashkenaz. Your question remains according to the Minhag Arizal.

Comment: Minhag Yerushalayim follows the Ari and AFAIK, it is the same as Ashkenaz.