# What is the correct bowing order?

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei, leil-shabbat, bowing-kneeling

In the end of the *Amidah*, in *Ose Shalom*, we bow to one side, to the other side and to the front, this is also done in the end of *Lecha Dodi*. I've always done this starting with left and then right (in both cases). But I've seen that some people do it the other way around.

Is there a correct order for bowing in these two cases?

Comment: In  the Yekkish shuls I'be attended, IIRC at the end of Lecho Dodi they bow towards the back/door at the first "Bo'i Kallo" and then turn around and bow again forward at the second "Bo'i Kallo".

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3376

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Lecha Dodi [yeshiva.org.il](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6624) says:

> Regarding bowing, R. Yakov Emdin brings that his father, the Chacham
>   Zvi, would bow three times when saying Bo’ee Kalah, to his left, then
>   his right and then in front. This is identical to the bowings
>   mentioned when we finish Shmoneh Esreh. The idea is because the
>   Shchina (Divine Presence) is, as if it were, before us (“I have set
>   Hashem always before me”, Tehilim 16, 8), so we bow to Her right (…
>   from His Right-hand (came the) fiery law”, Dvarim 33, 2) before Her
>   left, and then, as if it were, to Her.
>
> A significant difference should be pointed out, that the bowings at
>   the end of Shmoneh Esreh are cited in the Talmud (Yoma 53b) and the
>   Shulchan Aruch (Or. Ch. 123, 1) and are universally accepted, as
>   opposed to those at the end of Lecha Dodi, which is not cited by most
>   of the poskim and is a relatively recent custom of only some
>   communities.

Comment: To elaborate: _Lecha Dodi_ itself is of _recent_ vintage - compared to Talmudic practices.

Answer (score 3):

[Shulchan Aruch OC 123:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.123.1?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) says first left, then right.

> כּוֹרֵעַ וּפוֹסֵעַ ג' פְּסִיעוֹת לְאַחֲרָיו, בִּכְרִיעָה אַחַת, וְאַחַר שֶׁפָּסַע ג' פְּסִיעוֹת בְּעוֹדוֹ כּוֹרֵעַ, קֹדֶם שֶׁיִּזְקֹף, כְּשֶׁיֹּאמַר עוֹשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם בִּמְרוֹמָיו, הוֹפֵךְ פָּנָיו לְצַד שְׂמֹאלוֹ; וּכְשֶׁיֹּאמַר הוּא יַעֲשֶׂה שָׁלוֹם עָלֵינוּ, הוֹפֵךְ פָּנָיו לְצַד יְמִינוֹ; וְאַחַר כָּךְ יִשְׁתַּחֲוֶה לְפָנָיו, כְּעֶבֶד הַנִּפְטָר מֵרַבּוֹ.
>
> One bows and takes three steps backwards, all while still bowing. After the three steps, while still bowing and before straightening up: while saying "Oseh Shalom B'mromav" - turn one's head to the left; "Ya'aseh Shalom" - turn one's head to the right; then bow forward like a servant taking leave of the master.