# How to bow when saying "Bo i kalla"

Tags: bowing-kneeling, kabbalat-shabbat

During kaballat shabbat we sang lekha dodi and in the last stanza we bow and say the following: "bo i kala". Here, we bow to left and right. Some bow right to left and other left to right. Now I'm confused: which is the right way? And please elucidate the source of this.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3376 also. (The two preexisting questions are partial duplicates of one another, unfortunately.)